# U-SQL An output statement must have at least one local run error

Tags: u-sql

i m trying to play little bit with U-SQL. I want to run script locally but i m getting this error: "An output statement must have at least one local run error". I put my input file in data root directory and i just want to extract one column to the new file. Simple script just to see how it works.
Did i miss some step here?

Answer (score 3):

U-SQL scripts can either do DDL operations like `CREATE TABLE` or data output operations, in which case they must have an `OUTPUT` statement, something like this:

```
// Output results
OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```